# UnsubscriptionError thrown on first RX subscription

Tags: angular, zonejs

I am developing an Angular2 app for a couple of weeks now, and I ran into this a couple of days back.

The issue happens on the very first call to subscribe or toPromise on an rxJS stream, and doesn't seem to break app behaviour at all. It does, however, throw in the browser's console output, and seems to prevent debugging ( because the connection is lost between zone.js and the app? )

This happens regardless of which subscription is loaded first, and both in Google chrome and firefox alike.

I will try and update this question if I get more info, but at the moment this is all I know.

Very useless stacktrace:

```
browser_adapter.js:76 EXCEPTION: 
UnsubscriptionErrorBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:76
BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ browser_adapter.js:86
ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:56
(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:193
schedulerFn @ async.js:122
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:166
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:115
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:74
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:51
Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:124
Subject._next @ Subject.js:116
Subject.next @ Subject.js:73
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:11
1NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ ng_zone.js:119
NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:65
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:364
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:293
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:460
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)scheduleTask @ zone.js:100
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:373
Zone.longStackTraceZoneSpec.onScheduleTask @ long-stack-trace-zone.js:119
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:370
Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:310
(anonymous function) @ zone.js:121
send @ VM76503:3(
anonymous function) @ xhr_backend.js:76
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:58
Observable._subscribe @ Observable.js:99
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:55
Observable._subscribe @ Observable.js:99
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:55
AccountScreen.routerOnActivate @ account_screen.ts:56
(anonymous function) @ router_outlet.js:67
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:36
0NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.js:44
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:359
Zone.run @ zone.js:253
(anonymous function) @ zone.js:605
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:393
NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.js:35
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:392
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:290
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:511
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:463
```

Comment: Any idea what code causes the issue?

Comment: No, gets thrown at multiple places in *my* code. Haven't been able to track it down as far as angular innards are concerned, as it's deep inside a zone.onError subscription

Comment: Weird thing is - it didn't do this before. Now that it does, it does it even if I checkout an old branch and reinstall all npm modules.

Comment: Do you use some custom events with the `EventEmitter` class? Could you add the call where the error occurs? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, had to work in the meanwhile, Thierry. Found the problem.

Comment: @TiagoRoldão do you mind posting the solution as an answer? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Yeah, it seems an actual issue, was just creating it on github to link it here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug with `zone.js`. The last few betas of Angular depend on `zone.js@^0.6.6`which resolves to 0.6.9, which seems to be buggy.

Rolling back to 0.6.6 clears up the issue. A github issue has created [here](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/310).